# camera release issue in OpenCV

Tags: python, anaconda, environment, opencv

I'm using OpenCV in an environment that I had created in anaconda for using TensorFlow.
All functions work well but when I try to release the camera, it still is held by the application.
I'm using the simple code:-

```
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cam.release()
```

When I run it on the base(root) environment, it isn't a problem.
Should I add anything else to the environment?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Make sure you are reaching the cam.realease statement by putting a print statement above it.

Comment: @VardanAgarwal The problem I'm facing is that in spite of executing the release() function the camera is still on (webcam light is on)  and held up by the application ( preventing other applications from using the webcam).
I'm facing this problem only when I use OpenCV in any environment other than base(root) environment.